# Intractive Here map integration in React.js

Tags: reactjs, here-api

I am trying to make an interactive map with a draggable marker using HERE Technology Map service.
I have found a source on their page where they did the same in jquery.
function addDraggableMarker(map, behavior){

```
  var marker = new H.map.Marker({lat:42.35805, lng:-71.0636}, {
    // mark the object as volatile for the smooth dragging
    volatility: true
  });
  // Ensure that the marker can receive drag events
  marker.draggable = true;
  map.addObject(marker);

  // disable the default draggability of the underlying map
  // and calculate the offset between mouse and target's position
  // when starting to drag a marker object:
  map.addEventListener('dragstart', function(ev) {
    var target = ev.target,
        pointer = ev.currentPointer;
    if (target instanceof H.map.Marker) {
      var targetPosition = map.geoToScreen(target.getGeometry());
      target['offset'] = new H.math.Point(pointer.viewportX - targetPosition.x, pointer.viewportY - targetPosition.y);
      behavior.disable();
    }
  }, false);


  // re-enable the default draggability of the underlying map
  // when dragging has completed
  map.addEventListener('dragend', function(ev) {
    var target = ev.target;
    if (target instanceof H.map.Marker) {
      behavior.enable();
    }
  }, false);

  // Listen to the drag event and move the position of the marker
  // as necessary
   map.addEventListener('drag', function(ev) {
    var target = ev.target,
        pointer = ev.currentPointer;
    if (target instanceof H.map.Marker) {
      target.setGeometry(map.screenToGeo(pointer.viewportX - target['offset'].x, pointer.viewportY - target['offset'].y));
    }
  }, false);
}

/**
 * Boilerplate map initialization code starts below:
 */

//Step 1: initialize communication with the platform
// In your own code, replace variable window.apikey with your own apikey
var platform = new H.service.Platform({
  apikey: window.apikey
});
var defaultLayers = platform.createDefaultLayers();

//Step 2: initialize a map - this map is centered over Boston
var map = new H.Map(document.getElementById('map'),
  defaultLayers.vector.normal.map, {
  center: {lat:42.35805, lng:-71.0636},
  zoom: 12,
  pixelRatio: window.devicePixelRatio || 1
});
// add a resize listener to make sure that the map occupies the whole container
window.addEventListener('resize', () => map.getViewPort().resize());

//Step 3: make the map interactive
// MapEvents enables the event system
// Behavior implements default interactions for pan/zoom (also on mobile touch environments)
var behavior = new H.mapevents.Behavior(new H.mapevents.MapEvents(map));

// Step 4: Create the default UI:
var ui = H.ui.UI.createDefault(map, defaultLayers, 'en-US');

// Add the click event listener.
addDraggableMarker(map, behavior);
```

-> [Source](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/2.1.0/heremaps/maps-api-for-javascript-examples/tree/master/draggable-marker)

How I can convert that into a react class component?
I have never worked with jQuery before.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
class LocationMap extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      app_id: process.env.REACT_APP_PLACES_API_ID,
      app_code: process.env.REACT_APP_PLACES_APP_CODE,
      useCIT: true,
      useHTTPS: true,
      center: {
        lat: "26.9124",
        lng: "75.7873"
      },
      lat: null,
      lng: null,
      zoom: "12",
      theme: "normal.day",
      placeMarker: null,
      showFrontDrop: false,
      backdropShow: false,
      count: 0,
      dataLoaded: false,
      mapCentreText: this.props.mapLocation,
      count1: 0
    };
    this.platform = new window.H.service.Platform(this.state);
    this.map = null;
    this.mapCentreText = this.props.mapLocation;
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    // console.log(this.state.app_code, " is code");
    // console.log(this.state.app_id, "is app id");
    // this.platform = new window.H.service.Platform(this.state);
    // this.layer = this.platform.createDefaultLayers();
    // this.container = document.getElementById("main_map");
    // this.map = new window.H.Map(this.container, this.layer.normal.map, {
    //   center: this.state.center,
    //   zoom: this.state.zoom
    // });

    this.platform = new window.H.service.Platform(this.state);
    this.layer = this.platform.createDefaultLayers();
    this.container = document.getElementById("main_map");

    this.map = new window.H.Map(this.container, this.layer.normal.map, {
      center: this.state.center,
      zoom: this.state.zoom
    });
    this.group = new window.H.map.Group();
    var events = new window.H.mapevents.MapEvents(this.map);
    // eslint-disable-next-line
    this.behavior = new window.H.mapevents.Behavior(events);
    // eslint-disable-next-line
    var ui = new window.H.ui.UI.createDefault(this.map, this.layer);

    this.addDraggableMarker(this.map, this.behavior);
  }

  addDraggableMarker = (map, behavior) => {
    var marker = new window.H.map.Marker(
      this.state.center,
      this.state.volatility
    );

    marker.draggable = true;
    map.addObject(marker);

    map.addEventListener(
      "dragstart",
      function(ev) {
        var target = ev.target,
          pointer = ev.currentPointer;
        if (target instanceof window.H.map.Marker) {
          var targetPosition = map.geoToScreen(target.getGeometry());
          target["offset"] = new window.H.math.Point(
            pointer.viewportX - targetPosition.x,
            pointer.viewportY - targetPosition.y
          );
          behavior.disable();
        }
      },
      false
    );

    map.addEventListener(
      "dragend",
      function(ev) {
        var target = ev.target;
        if (target instanceof window.H.map.Marker) {
          behavior.enable();
        }
      },
      false
    );
    map.addEventListener(
      "drag",
      function(ev) {
        var target = ev.target,
          pointer = ev.currentPointer;
        if (target instanceof window.H.map.Marker) {
          target.setGeometry(
            map.screenToGeo(
              pointer.viewportX - target["offset"].x,
              pointer.viewportY - target["offset"].y
            )
          );
        }
      },
      false
    );
  };
  render() {
    return <div id="main_map">Sample</div>;
  }
}
```

I am getting these error in the console
[image]

Comment: just FYI: There is no jQuery used in this draggable marker example.

Answer (score 0):

First, remove `this.platform = new window.H.service.Platform(this.state)` from the component constructor and only initialise it in the `componentDidMount` life cycle method as you have already done. Also, with the Map JS API version 3.1, you need to pass `apiKey` (mandatory parameter) to the platform service (instead of `app_id` and `app_code` which are for older versions) like so:

`this.platform = new window.H.service.Platform({apiKey: <api key here>});`

You can generate the `apiKey` from you HERE developer portal under projects, JAVASCRIPT and then create a key.